# setTimeout not working in my new Kendo MVC project

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, setup-project

When my javascript files gets to the setTimeout function, it throws this following error:

> TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

The function is inside the 'global.js' file (shown in the _layout.cshtml) and is called from a `$(document).ready` in my view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadGameStartupWindow();
});
```

My javascript file (continueCountdown is where it throws the error):

```
function loadGameStartupWindow() {
    var window = $("#GameStartupWindow").data("kendoWindow");

    window.center().open();
}

function beginCountdown() {
    for (var i = 5; i > 0; i = i - 1) {
        continueCountdown(i);
    }
}

function continueCountdown(i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#countdownNumber").text(i);
    }, 1000);
}
```

My _layout.cshtml:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/2018.3.911/css")

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/_references.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryVal")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")

@Styles.Render("~/Content/Site.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/global.js")
```

Bundles Config:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryVal").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                 "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                 "~/Content/Site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
            "~/Scripts/kendo/2018.3.911/kendo.all.min.js",
            // "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.timezones.min.js", // uncomment if using the Scheduler
            "~/Scripts/kendo/2018.3.911/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/2018.3.911/css").Include(
            "~/Content/kendo/2018.3.911/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/2018.3.911/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"));

        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
    }
```

Can anyone tell me if i'm missing anything here?

Comment: You are in strict mode so 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' cannot be accessed.

Comment: Oh, i've never heard of this before haha, I shouldn't of assumed it was an error loading the javascript

Answer (score 0):

Using setTimeout in this way meant that my function entered 'strict mode' and so here is my work-around:

```
function beginCountdown() {
var i = 5;
setInterval(function () {
    if (i != 0) {
        $("#countdownNumber").text(i);
        i = i - 1;
    } else {
        clearInterval();
    }

}, 1000)
}
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode